# Selecting value from dropdown and getting it hidden value

Tags: javascript, python, select, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

So I am currently learning beautiful soup and I am trying to figure out how to select drop down value and then getting it hidden associate value.

Link I am using is http://www.nakedcph.com/commodity/4876-nike-sportswear-air-max-95.

[This is a html code I am referencing to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3NCe.png)

I am trying to select values from commodity-show-form-size and after selecting it, I am trying to pull

> name="item_pid" id="commodity-show-form-item_pid" value

I tested it out manually by selecting size and changing input type to show using inspect element. And it worked. But when I try to do it on python, I get

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

This is my code

```
import requests
import re
import time
import timeit
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

session = requests.session()
response = session.get('http://www.nakedcph.com/commodity/4876-nike-sportswear-air-max-95')
soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
select = soup.find('select', id="commodity-show-form-size")
option_tags = select.findAll('option')
print option_tags
```

I been stuck on this for hour. Please help
Everyone is recommending I do it through javascript. Could someone provide some example for me?

Comment: The element you are reffering to is generated by javascript and javascript doesn't work very well with BS. consider using selenium

Comment: Is there no other way to do this? I hate selenium because it slow and just very unconvient for me

Answer (score 0):

If your page is javascript rendered you can try something like this:

```
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = dryscrape.Session()
url = 'http://www.nakedcph.com/commodity/4876-nike-sportswear-air-max-95'
session.visit(url)
response = session.body()
soup=BeautifulSoup(response)
print soup.select('input#commodity-show-form-item_pid')
```

Comment: I am having problem installing dryscrape. I try pip install but I got running install
running build
'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

The data you wanted is generated by JavaScript, you can find it in the html code:

```
import re
text = '''$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#commodity-show-thumbnails').bxSlider({ mode: 'vertical', auto: false, controls: true, pager: false, minSlides: 4, maxSlides: 4, moveSlides: 1, slideWidth: 250 });
    itemSelector('commodity-show-form', 'commodity-show-addcart-submit', [['color', 'Choose color'], ['size', 'Choose size']], { "39757": { "params": ["White/Pure Platinum", "35,5"]}, "39758": { "params": ["White/Pure Platinum", "36"]}, "39759": { "params": ["White/Pure Platinum", "36,5"]}, "39760": { "params": ["White/Pure Platinum", "37,5"]}, "39761": { "params": ["White/Pure Platinum", "38"]}, "39762": { "params": ["White/Pure Platinum", "38,5"]}, "39763": { "params": ["White/Pure Platinum", "39"]}, "39764": { "params": ["White/Pure Platinum", "40"]}, "39765": { "params": ["White/Pure Platinum", "40,5"]}, "39766": { "params": ["White/Pure Platinum", "41"]}, "39767": { "params": ["White/Pure Platinum", "42"]} }, [39757,39758,39759,39760,39761,39762,39763,39764,39765,39766,39767], 'main-cart', 'commodity-show-image');
});'''

res = re.findall(r'{ "params": (.+?)}', text)  # get text format

to_list = [eval(i) for i in res] # text to python object list

print(to_list)
```

out:

```
[['White/Pure Platinum', '35,5'], ['White/Pure Platinum', '36'], ['White/Pure Platinum', '36,5'], ['White/Pure Platinum', '37,5'], ['White/Pure Platinum', '38'], ['White/Pure Platinum', '38,5'], ['White/Pure Platinum', '39'], ['White/Pure Platinum', '40'], ['White/Pure Platinum', '40,5'], ['White/Pure Platinum', '41'], ['White/Pure Platinum', '42']]
```

Comment: How would I parse it to get the value I want? I am not familiar with javascript at all. Could you provide some example

Comment: you should use regex to extract data from script string. you can treat script tag like bs's tag, they can be find using find().

Comment: I managed to get the the javascript using soup.find but how do I parse it in a way that would give me the corresponding value for corresponding size?